# Oxyplot: disable tracker

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I have several series, and I need to disable tracker for some of them only. How do I do that?

```
 <oxy:Plot.Series>
      <oxy:AreaSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PowerValues}" Smooth="False" StrokeThickness="1" Foreground="#6B303030" Color="White"  Color2="#00000000"
                                    Fill="{StaticResource FillColor}" BrokenLineColor="Red"></oxy:AreaSeries>
                    <oxy:StairStepSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PowerTemplateMax}" Smooth="False" StrokeThickness="2" Color="Green" IsManipulationEnabled="False">
                    </oxy:StairStepSeries>
                    <oxy:StairStepSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PowerTemplateMin}" Smooth="False" StrokeThickness="2" Color="Yellow"></oxy:StairStepSeries>
                </oxy:Plot.Series>
```

`AreaSeries` should have the trakcer, when both `StairStepSeries` should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this using a Custom Tracker, which is invisible. For example, You could define your tracker as.

```
    <oxy:PlotView.TrackerDefinitions>
        <oxy:TrackerDefinition TrackerKey="InvisibleTracker">
            <oxy:TrackerDefinition.TrackerTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </oxy:TrackerDefinition.TrackerTemplate>
        </oxy:TrackerDefinition>
    </oxy:PlotView.TrackerDefinitions>
```

Notice you have set the visibility of `TextBlock` as `Collapsed`. You can now set the TrackerKey for the series for which you need to hide the Tracker to "InvisibleTracker". This would ensure tracker is not visible for those series.